# Move filtered data to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column `ema_email` which is supposed to contain email addresses, but you can see it sometimes contains phone numbers. Here's a sample from that column

```
864-943-1333
864-963-5302
864-987-3401
877-225-2922
888-211-3261 702
914-433-6205
917-767-7124
a.titus37@gmail.com
aaudreyisrael@gmail.com
abiblew@aol.com
acash@rrhlawfirm.com
acl@lewisbabcock.com
acreighton@fujifilm.com
adam.milstein@hagerpacific.com
Adelaide@islc.net
aellefson@hsblawfirm.com
afm@fairwayford.com
agarrard@henrypak.com
agnewdev1@aol.com
ajmaeurer@aol.com
akearse@motleyrice.com
akunz@turnerpadget.com
al.siegel@asiegelandassoc.com
alanscc@gmail.com
alexevins@parkerpoe.com
Alinaohene@me.com
```

Is there a way that I can filter out these phone numbers and possibly move them to the right column? Or will I have to do this manually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question slightly to make it easier to understand what your issue is. If these are actual email addresses and phone numbers, I would recommend anonymizing them so you don't breach anyone's privacy.

Comment: Thanks and no they are all bogus numbers and addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's same table, and also same row ust copy column value if it's not an e-mail address:

```
update tablename set phoneno = ema_email
  where ema_email not like '%@%'
```

Perhaps you want to clear the ema_email value also, then add `ema_email = NULL`

If it's another table (or row), I need more info to know what to do!

Comment: OK this is close just..and different tables std_IndividualeMail and std_Phone - pho_number are I can link on my ind_guid

Comment: So why don't you edit your question and add table definitions!